# Google Sheet - Defining Churn based on the set of criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, saas

I have a dataset with all the subscriptions I receive on a monthly or yearly basis from my clients. There are 3 columns: client IDs, Subscription charge at (date), subscription type (monthly or yearly).

I want to add 2 columns to get visibility on

- whether a client has churned or is still an  existing client.
- The last subscription date

To be consider a churn, a client has to:

- Not have made any new subscription during the last 90 days if the last subscription type is monthly
- Not have made any new subscription during the last 1 year and 90 days if the last subscription type is yearly

I've made a [dummy sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NzobVdY9AGAT-eyJIpR8ECjjQQ6EOYqumuBgKZHbKlo/edit#gid=0) to help better understand my issue.
Any help on the formulas in column E and F would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can get the formula and the result in `Neo Test sheet` in your dummy sheet**

As you can easily get today's date, here's a working formula giving your expected result :

```
=IF(
    D3="Monthly",
    SI(
        DAYS($A$1,F3)<=90,
        "Still a client",
        "Churned"
    ),
    IF(
        DAYS($A$1,F3)<=365+90,
        "Still a client",
        "Churned"
    )
)
```

Checks the subscribtion type, then get the day's difference ( you can replace `$A$1` by `Today()` ).
If it's before the deadline it's still a client, if not it's churned

Comment: thanks for your answer. When I add the date I'm looking for on column F => =maxifs(C:C, B:B, B3) then your formula works.